# add_done_call_back() gives AttributeError: 'Future' object has no attribute 'select'

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, threadpool, concurrent.futures

I tried making a simple web crawler.

I want to create a data frame with the parent link and the links that are found on the parent link page along with the text associated with it.

[image]

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from queue import Queue, Empty
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import urllib
from urllib.error import HTTPError #used in the main function, to catch HTTPErrors
from requests.exceptions import InvalidURL #used in the main function, to catch invalidUrl errors
from urllib.parse import urlparse #used to parse the homepage url and get network location out of it
from urllib.parse import quote #used to correct incorrect urls
import pandas as pd


class MultiThreadScraper:

    global df
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=None, columns = ['parent_link','link', 'text'])
    
    def __init__(self, base_url):

        self.base_url = base_url
        self.root_url = '{}://{}'.format(urlparse(self.base_url).scheme, urlparse(self.base_url).netloc)
        self.pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=20)
        self.scraped_pages = set([])
        self.to_crawl = Queue()
        self.to_crawl.put(self.base_url)
    
    #gets http.client.HTTPResponse from the server
    def get_http_response(self, url):
        header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.11',
                      'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
                      'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
                      'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
                      'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
                      'Connection': 'keep-alive'}
        request = urllib.request.Request(url, headers = header) #urllib.request.Request object
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)  #http.client.HTTPResponse
        return response

    #accepts the http.client.HTTPResponse from the server and fetches the html content using BeautifulSoup
    def get_html_content(self, httpResponse):
        httpResponse_content = httpResponse.read() #data in bytes
        httpResponse_htmlContent = BeautifulSoup(httpResponse_content, 'html.parser')
        return httpResponse_htmlContent
        
    def parse_links(self, html,df):
        all_tags_with_hrefs = html.select('[href]')
        for link in all_tags_with_hrefs:
            url = link['href']
            if url.startswith('/') or url.startswith(self.root_url):
                url = urljoin(self.root_url, url)
                if (link.text).strip()!='':
                    df.loc[-1,'parent_link']= self.base_url
                    df.loc[-1,'link'] = url
                    df.loc[-1,'text'] = (link.text).strip() 
                    df.drop_duplicates(subset='link', inplace=True)
                    df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
                if url not in self.scraped_pages:
                    self.to_crawl.put(url)

    def post_scrape_callback(self, html_content):
            self.parse_links(html_content, df)

    def scrape_page(self, url):
        try:
            url = urllib.parse.quote(url, safe='/,:,-,?,=,&')
            get_response = self.get_http_response(url)
            try: 
                html_content = self.get_html_content(get_response)
            except:
                print(f'{url} : ERROR READING RESPONSE !')
        except(HTTPError, InvalidURL):
            print(f'{url} : NO RESPONSE !')
        return html_content
        

    def run_scraper(self):
        while True:
            try:
                target_url = self.to_crawl.get(timeout=10)
                if target_url not in self.scraped_pages:
                    print("Scraping URL: {}".format(target_url))
                    self.scraped_pages.add(target_url)
                    job = self.pool.submit(self.scrape_page, target_url)
                    job.add_done_callback(self.post_scrape_callback)
            except Empty:
                return
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                continue
if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = MultiThreadScraper("https://www.nationalgrid.com/")
    s.run_scraper()
```

It gives me the following error :
**AttributeError: 'Future' object has no attribute 'select'**
From documentation I understood that add_done_callback() adds a callback to be run when the Future is done.
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You will need a pool and to split your code logic to smaller functions that can run independently.
For example if you write a `crawl` function that receives a URL as the argument you can do something like:

```py
import concurrent.futures
urls = [] # a url list you create
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    for url in urls:
        executor.submit(crawl, url)
```

Then you can parse multiple URLs using multiple threads (here it's limited to 5)

Comment: but the list of urls is not constant.. it keeps on changing. everytime a url from the list is parsed, a set of new urls found on that url is added to the list of urls that need to be crawled..

Comment: You can create a shared queue of URLs that the pool of threads checks (and pops the head at each time)

Comment: I tried modifying the code with help of some sample code I found online. It still doesn't run..